# How do I prove two applications of the absurd pattern result in the same in Cubical Agda?

Tags: agda, category-theory, cubical-type-theory

Heavy category theory (agda-categories) related question.

I'm trying to define a natural transformation and prove its naturality square commutes. Essentially, the error I run into is that *two "applications" of a function that takes in the empty type* (so ex falso quodlibdet principle) fail to return the same type.  Here's the relevant hole:

```
plugin1unit : NaturalTransformation idF (constantPolynomial ∘F plugIn1)
plugin1unit = record { 
    η = λ X → (λ x → x , λ _ → tt) ⇄ λ fromPos () ;
    commute = λ f@(mapDir ⇄ mapPos) -> {!   !} ;
   }
}
```

The type of the `commute` hole is:

```
((λ x → Arrow.mapPosition f x , (λ _ → tt)) ⇄
       (λ fromPos z → Arrow.mapDirection f fromPos ((λ ()) z)))
      Cubical.≡
      ((λ x → Arrow.mapPosition f x , (λ x₁ → tt)) ⇄
       (λ fromPos z → (λ ()) z))
```

I don't want to include all the supporting definitions; I'll only include, in the "appendix" (end of the question) the definitions of the `Polynomial` type and its `Arrow` and so as to not flood this post with information. The error I get is simple. If I refine that hole enough, here's what I get, step-by-step:
1.

```
    commute = λ f@(mapDir ⇄ mapPos) -> λ i → {!   !} ;
```

goal type:

```
Arrow X
      (MkPolynomial
       (Σ (Polynomial.position Y₁) (λ x → Polynomial.direction Y₁ x → ⊤))
       (λ _ → ⊥))
```

2. (some auto-solving/only obvious thing to do omitted)

```
    commute = λ f@(mapDir ⇄ mapPos) -> λ i → (λ x → mapDir x , λ x₁ → tt) ⇄ {!   !} ;
```

goal type:

```
(fromPos : Polynomial.position X) →
      ⊥ → Polynomial.direction X fromPos
```

3. this refines to a function of two arguments, of course, one of which is the empty type  ⊥:

```
    commute = λ f@(mapDir ⇄ mapPos) -> λ i → (λ x → mapDir x , λ x₁ → tt) ⇄ λ fromPos x → {!   !} ;
```

but the obvious solution, of empty pattern matching, doesn't work with the following error:
`(λ { fromPos () }) fromPos z != Arrow.mapDirection f fromPos ((λ ()) z)`

If I define a function that is _much more general than the requested type `(fromPos : Polynomial.position X) → ⊥ → Polynomial.direction X fromPos`:

```
fromAnythingToAnythingElse : {A B : Set} -> A -> ⊥ -> B
fromAnythingToAnythingElse x ()
```

and try to put it in the hole at step two, I get another error about inability of instantiating metavariables.

Here's another version of what I believe to be the essential error: [image: How can "(λ ()) z" be different from ANYTHING? By definition it returns any type!]

How can "(λ ()) z" be *different* from ANYTHING? By definition it returns *any* type!

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered without access to the partial solution you're working on, in a form where the Agda tools can understand them and give guidance. Is it possible to share the code you're working on?

Comment: @mudri Yes, here's the code: https://gist.github.com/amuricys/d021e98b1a788f8ae414d85428564db4
There's a lot of supporting definitions (and sorry it's so messy) but the problematic holes are at the very end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found two solutions to this problem, which I will present on a minimal example. I have tested them both on your original problem, but will leave the details of adapting these solutions as a small exercise. I call these solutions the “right solution”, based on building an expression to fit the goal in your file, and the “left solution”, based on taking advantage of (co)pattern-matching (sometimes known as “programming on the left”) as a means to decompose the problem.

It may be worth noting that Agda 2.6.3 – specifically, the introduction of `--cubical-compatible` – breaks the code of the original question because agda-categories is written with `--without-K` but not (yet?) `--cubical-compatible`.

## The problem (but simpler)

Let's start with the following file. `--postfix-projections` is optional, but I like it and will use it later (in a non-essential way; it's just surface syntax).

```
{-# OPTIONS --postfix-projections --cubical #-}
module Gist where

open import Cubical.Core.Everything
open import Cubical.Foundations.Everything

open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Product
```

Then, we can define two definitionally distinct functions of type `⊥ → ⊥`:

```
id-⊥ : ⊥ → ⊥
id-⊥ x = x

!-⊥ : ⊥ → ⊥
!-⊥ ()
```

These functions are cubically equal by a simple argument `eq`.
We can see that they are definitionally distinct because the proof cannot be `refl`.

```
eq : id-⊥ ≡ !-⊥
eq i ()
```

So far, so good. However, when we try to do a bigger proof quickly using interval variables, things fall apart. Here I use `Path` rather than `_≡_` so as to give a type annotation to the pairs, because the type of the second component of a Σ-type is always unclear in lieu of annotations or contextual information.

```
eq2 : Path ((⊥ → ⊥) × (⊥ → ⊥)) (id-⊥ , id-⊥) (id-⊥ , !-⊥)
eq2 i = id-⊥ , λ ()

{-
x != (λ ()) x of type ⊥
when checking the definition of eq2
-}
```

What's wrong with this is that `eq2 i0 = id-⊥ , λ ()`, where we expected it to be `id-⊥ , id-⊥`, matching the left-hand side of the equation we are trying to prove. When we define a path in cubical Agda, we have to check that the endpoints of each clause match definitionally when each interval variable is instantiated to `i0` and `i1`. In `eq`, we had no checks to do because there were no clauses, whereas `eq2` has a clause (signified by the `=` sign), and that clause fails one of the tests.

## Right solution

Looking at the type of `eq2` from a standard Agda perspective, the thing that jumps out at us is that both sides of the equation share a head constructor `_,_` and the first component `id-⊥`. This is a prime candidate for a `cong` lemma. Unfortunately for us, the `cong` lemma from the cubical library allows full dependent Π-types for its function argument, making `cong (id-⊥ ,_) ?` suffer the same under-specification as what made us use `Path` above. Handily, however, `Cubical.Foundations.Path` provides a simpler lemma `cong′` (quoted verbatim from the library):

```
-- Less polymorphic version of `cong`, to avoid some unresolved metas
cong′ : ∀ {B : Type ℓ'} (f : A → B) {x y : A} (p : x ≡ y)
      → Path B (f x) (f y)
cong′ f = cong f
{-# INLINE cong′ #-}
```

Using that lemma, we get our first solution:

```
eq2r : Path ((⊥ → ⊥) × (⊥ → ⊥)) (id-⊥ , id-⊥) (id-⊥ , !-⊥)
eq2r = cong′ (id-⊥ ,_) (λ { i () })
```

Note that, at the top level, `eq2r` is not defining a path via abstraction of an interval variable, so no boundary checks are required there. The extended λ-expression `λ { i () }` would be subject to boundary checks, except that it has no clauses to check (being essentially an inlining of `eq`). Note that `λ i ()`, which is equivalent to `λ i → λ ()`, does not work, because it has one clause returning `λ ()`, which is not definitionally equal to `id-⊥`.

## Left solution

When diagnosing the problem with `eq2`, we found that it had a clause, making it susceptible to boundary checks. In the right solution, we pushed the abstraction of the interval variable inside the clause, making the top-level definition not susceptible to boundary checks, and then eventually making a clausal definition of a path when we could refute any clauses.

Perhaps a more direct way to use cubical features is to ask *Can we make the type of the path we're defining smaller?*. The type `(⊥ → ⊥) × (⊥ → ⊥)` has quite a few moving parts, so if we can dig into it and just work at type `⊥`, things might become simpler. To that end, we take an interval variable `i`, and then do a match with copatterns `proj₁` and `proj₂` to produce a pair. In the first case, we want a `⊥ → ⊥` which is `id-⊥` when `i = i0` and `id-⊥` when `i = i1`. `id-⊥` suffices. In the second case, `id-⊥` and `!-⊥` don't match on-the-nose, so we take an argument `x : ⊥` and then match on `x` so as to not have any clauses to check. Note that the latter case is essentially an inlining of `eq i`.

```
eq2l : Path ((⊥ → ⊥) × (⊥ → ⊥)) (id-⊥ , id-⊥) (id-⊥ , !-⊥)
eq2l i .proj₁ = id-⊥
eq2l i .proj₂ ()
```

I'll let you decide which solution you prefer. I believe they behave equivalently, except maybe in some corner cases not respecting η-equality for records, like `with`. The behaviour of copatterns with respect to η for records may also have some performance implications for type-checking, which IIRC favour the left solution.

Comment: Wonderful! This stuff is super subtle.

(I haven't changed agda-categories to `--cubical-compatible` because I have not had the time to measure how bad a slowdown that will be.)

Comment: @JacquesCarette Yeah, it would make a lot of sense to me if the performance cost outweighed the benefits of `--cubical-compatible` in the case of agda-categories, given how much it strains the type-checker in terms of performance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to. It is consistent that there are multiple such functions. It is also consistent that there is only one.

When I ran into that issue (one of Laplaza's coherence conditions for Rig Categories when specialized to Agda's Set hinges on this), I solved it by carefully **not** matching on `()` but instead passing the impossibility through.

My guess is that there is some very subtle interactions between your definitions that you'll need to puzzle out to get there.

TL;DR: don't prematurely match `()`. That might not be the coherent definition.

Comment: The question mentions *cubical* Agda, in which it is not consistent for there to be multiple distinct, extensionally equal functions.

Comment: But it is consistent for `()` to have any number of inhabitants. Once you've destroyed the universe, it's amazing what becomes true... You can't prove that two bottom-yielding functions are equal, even with functional extensionality, basically because you can prove that two bottoms are both equal and unequal.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your comment, because `()` is not a type, and thus does not have inhabitants. For the second part, I can easily prove that any two functions of type `⊥ → ⊥` are equal in cubical Agda: Take `i : I` and `x : ⊥`, and match `x` as `()`. Precisely because the context is inconsistent, I can prove whatever I want.

Comment: I'm also confused. It's not just any bottom yielding functions, it's two functions that take bottom and produce something. Like I said in the question, here's a much more general proof than what I'm stuck on:
```fromAnythingToFalseToAnythingEqual : {A B : Set} {w z : A -> ⊥ -> B} -> w ≡ z
fromAnythingToFalseToAnythingEqual i x ()
```
I take your point of not matching prematurely on `()`, but I don't have anywhere to pass the absurdity to.

Comment: Sorry @mudri I didn't have access to the right unicode and so I took some ASCII liberties that I shouldn't have. 

On the second point: I can *also* prove they are NOT equal, by the same reasoning!!!

Comment: @AndréMuricy The way I read 1.1.5 of https://mat.uab.cat/~kock/cat/polynomial.pdf , your definition of constant polynomial is incorrect. You should be mapping to \top not \bottom.

Comment: @JacquesCarette I'm following https://topos.site/poly-book.pdf instead of Kock's notes (though I am aware of them) but I don't see what you're saying. Keep in mind this is not the constant polynomial ENDOfunctor Set -> Set p(y) = A (an object in Poly), but rather a functor Set -> Poly that sends a set to this object. The target polynomial therefore must have 0 directions (all terms are raised to exponent 0)